How to allow Teams bot to send direct message to user without user adding the bot
I created a teams bot app using the developer portal. I added the following permissions which as to my understanding will let me send messages to users who haven't install my bot but are a part of a team that installed the bot.
Developer portal app permissions
I understood that I should firstly create a conversation for the bot and the user so I tried using the following API
POST https://smba.trafficmanager.net/teams/v3/conversations

{
"bot": {
"id": "ASDAD"
},
"members": [
{
"id": "sdas"
}
],
"channelData": {
"tenant": {
"id": "asdasd"
}
}
}

The response was
Bot is not installed in user's personal scope
How can I achieve sending messages to users when there isn't an active conversation?
(Im using go)
I tried using the API conversations API described in the details section.
I tried sending a message without creating a conversation

It's not possible at all I'm afraid - the bot HAS to have been installed by the user. I guess it stops someone creating a "Spam" bot, especially across tenants. What -is- possible though is to call the Graph API to auto-install the bot app for the user if it's not there. I've given a more full answer on both of these topics over here: Sending proactive messages from an outside process to organizational users via Teams chat bot
